# Enable or Disable products for specific store in magento

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I am creating website in magento 2.3 and i am new in magento. I have products and I have created multi stores. I want to **enable/disable specific products for specific stores**. I have googled it but didn't find any solution. I am trying to find that option to enable/disable but I am unable to find.
**Here is the screenshot:**
[image]
**Please help me**

Answer (score 1):

You can filter products by store view wise and enable/disable products by store view wise not store wise.

[image]

after filter products by store view wise then select by check box to product then in Action drop down have option change status to enable/disable.
after that clear cache and re-index so it will update on frontend as well.

Comment: How can I `enable/disable` products by store view wise? Ss is only about to filter.

Comment: after filter products by store view wise then select by check box to product then in Action drop down have option change status to enable/disable.

Comment: I've unabled all products for my store 1 view but it's not showing in front-end. it's giving me still "We can't find products matching the selection."

Comment: re-index and clear the cache.

Comment: @ZainShabir: if its worked then please accept answer so, it will help to other also.

Comment: Yeah it's okay, that other one is a new issue

Comment: @ZainShabir: if you face any problem you can create a questions so it will easy to help you.

Comment: @SangeetaJain That solution you gave me as an answer didn't work. **I apply filter first of store (where i want to enable/disable product -> Then i select product and change his status to disable)**, Now disabling that product for specific store is disabling that product for all stores. Why?

Comment: @SangeetaJain I've created question for this, you can check https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/292018/disabling-product-in-specific-store-is-disabling-that-product-in-all-stores/292022?noredirect=1#comment419466_292022

Comment: after that clear cache and re-index so it will update on frontend as well. below command for run index and clear cache.
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush