# Disabling product in specific store is disabling that product in all stores

Tags: magento2

I am creating multistore website in magento. I've created multistores and I am trying to disable product for specific store. I am doing it like this:

```
 1. In products page (admin), Filters -> Choose Store and apply filter
 2. Select product and change status to disable
```

**Here is the screenshot:**
[image]
[image]
[image]

**My Stores Screenshot:**
[image]

When i disable choosed product in specific store then it is disabling that product in all stores. Why? Even I've applied filter that i want to disable that product only in that specific store. **Please help me.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the following commands in root folder of your M2 application one by one:

```
chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/static/ app/etc/ pub/media/
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Reload page.

Comment: It's giving me error when i run first command `'chmod' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: ok leave first command run remaining two one by one

Comment: I did, but it didn't work. I am disabling product for store `shop 1` but It's disabling that product for all store

Comment: update your question with your manage stores page

Comment: I've updated my question with screenshot. Please check

Comment: you have one base web so can you please enable back products & try visiblity attribute as per store or store view level. Mean put not visible individually at store level where you dont want to show product.

Comment: It worked, but it will be one by one, can't select multiple

Comment: how much products you have ?

Comment: More than 2000 products